# Javascript code for tabs to load specific file when clicked

Tags: javascript, select, tabs

We are working on a order form page which will load a specific order form file when a tab has been selected.

See here, http://www.psd2htmlpros.com/dev/order-form3/

The site already have working tabs on this page, http://www.psd2htmlpros.com/service.html

However the issue is that when someone clicks one of the tabs on the order form page (http://www.psd2htmlpros.com/dev/order-form3/) it adds a # sign to the end of the URL and then breaks other parts of the form. For example.

If I click on the Gold Package you'll notice that it will add a # (pound) sign to the end or the page URL and then try to click one of the options under the "Additional Options" area, the tabs won't open.

Here is the JS code currently being used.

Does anybody know how to fix that so it doesn't not add the # (pound) sign after one of the packages have been selected?

//--------- Code Starts Here -----------//

```
<div class="order-form-tabs">

<ul class="nav">

<li><h2><a id="silver" href="#" class="current curved-top" rel="tab1">Silver Package</a></h2><h4 style="padding:10px 0;">$97</h4><strong>Package Includes:</strong><br /><i>XHTML 1.0 Transitional/CSS 2.1<br />100% Hand-coded and W3C Valid<br />Table-less markup<br />Optimized Shorthand CSS<br />Cross-browser compatibility</i></li>

<li><h2><a id="gold" href="#" class="curved-top" rel="tab2">Gold Package</a></h2><h4 style="padding:10px 0;">$148</h4><strong>Package Includes:</strong><br /><i>XHTML 1.0 Strict/CSS 2.1<br />100% Hand-coded and W3C Valid<br />Table-less markup<br />Optimized Shorthand CSS<br />Cross-browser compatibility<br />SEO Semantic Coding<br />Complete Presentational Separation<br />Load Speed Optimization</i></li>

<li><h2><a id="platinum" href="#" class="curved-top" rel="tab3">Platinum Package</a></h2><h4 style="padding:10px 0;">$188</h4><strong>Package Includes:</strong><br /><i>HTML5/CSS3<br />100% Hand-coded and W3C Valid<br />Table-less markup<br />Optimized Shorthand CSS<br />Cross-browser compatibility<br />SEO Semantic Coding<br />Complete Presentational Separation<br />Load Speed Optimization</i></li></li>

</ul>

<div class="separator"></div>


<div id="tab1">

<?php include "order-silver.php" ?>

</div>


<div id="tab2">

</div>


<div id="tab3">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#silver').click(function(){
    $("#tab1").load("order-silver.php");
    $('#tab2').empty();
    $('#tab3').empty();
});

$('#gold').click(function(){
    $("#tab2").load("order-gold.php");
    $('#tab1').empty();
    $('#tab3').empty();
});

$('#platinum').click(function(){
    $("#tab3").load("order-platinum.php");
    $('#tab1').empty();
    $('#tab2').empty();
});

</script>

</div>
```

//--------- Code Ends Here -----------//